# Capybara + FactoryGirl, set relationship in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

I'm a newcomer when it comes to both `Capybara` `FactoryGirl`, In my Rails app I have a relationship that looks like this:

```
# App.rb
belong_to :plan

# Plan.rb
has_many :apps
```

Each app must have a plan, in my App.rb model I do it like this: `before_save :set_default_plan, on: :create`.

I want to test that app creation works, using Capybara integration tests. I currently have a test that looks like this:

```
require "rails_helper"

include Warden::Test::Helpers
Warden.test_mode!

describe "adding apps" do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before { login_as(user, scope: :user) }

  it "allows a user to create an app" do
    visit apps_path
    fill_in "App name", with: "My App"
    click_on "create_app_button"
    visit apps_path
    expect(page).to have_content("My App")
  end
end
```

After I create apps I render this in my view: `#{app.plan.free_requests}`. If I run my tests with `bundle exec rspec` I currently get this error:

```
undefined method `free_requests' for nil:NilClass
```

In my app I also use FactoryGirl to test my models. I have the following (relevant) factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :app do
    name "Test"
    [...]
    association :plan, :factory => :plan
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :plan do
    name "Default"
    [...]
  end
end
```

I wonder how I should set ut my factories and test suite to make this test become a green one.

Can I either assign a plan to the app I'm creating somehow with Capybara, or can I create a default association / plan for my app with FactoryGirl. Is is there another approach? Thankful for all assistance.

**Update**

This is how my `set_default_plan` method looks:

```
# App.rb
def set_default_plan
  if self.new_record?
    plan = Plan.find_by_stripe_id("default_plan")
    if plan.nil? == false
      self.plan = plan
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FactoryGirl really shouldn't have anything to do with "apps" or "plans" in your test, since you're running through your controllers create action, unless `set_default_plan` doesn't actually create a plan if none exist.  If that is the case then you could use FactoryGirl to create the required plan like - `FactoryGirl.create(:plan)` in your before block

You should also specify that the plan is a required association (this is default in Rails 5 so if you're using that this may not be necessary) which will prevent your Apps from being created without a plan.

```
# App.rb
belongs_to :plan, required: true
```

Another thing to note is you should always check for confirmation after clicking a button that performs an action before visiting another page.  This is because the result of clicking the button is not guaranteed to be synchronous so visiting another page immediately can kill the action request.

```
click_on "create_app_button"
expect(page).to have_content("App Created!!!")  # whatever text is shown on success
visit apps_path
```

Comment: Thanks! I do use Rails 5. I tried to change and check for confirmation instead of the app name. But I still have my original problem that the test complains about my apps plan being nil. `set_default_plan` does not create a plan if no one exists. Any ideas on how to solve my nil plan issue?

Comment: @Anders so if it doesn't create a new plan how does it know which plan to associate with the app? Maybe add your `set_default_plan` code to the question

Comment: I have added that to my question now.

Comment: ok - so you need to create a plan that would match that stripe_id - something like  `FactoryGirl.create(:plan, stripe_id: 'getlingo_default')` in your before block.  Also - if an app has to have a plan, you probably don't want to just do nothing if the default plan can't be found - so you might want to do  `Plan.find_by_stripe_id!("getlingo_default")` instead (  ! so it raises an exception if the plan doesn't exist )